# Issues while updating cell in R shiny datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to add an editable datatable in r shiny. I have two components to it. First being allowing the user to add a new row and delete a selected row. Secondly when the user changes any value in the cell it should update the corresponding cell. The issue I am facing is if the user edits column `dd` it should update the value for column `ff` based on the formula. Also when I edit a cell and add new rows the new columns come up as blanks. How can I fix this.Thank you.

```
### Libraries
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

### Data
input_data <- data.frame(aa = c("Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3"),
                         bb = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                         cc = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         dd = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                         ee = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         ff = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         gg = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### Shiny App
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    mainPanel(

      actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
      actionButton("add_btn", "Add"),
      actionButton("delete_btn", "Delete"),
      tags$hr(),
      DT::dataTableOutput("mod_table")    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    #demodata<-input_data

    this_table <- reactiveVal(input_data)

    observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
      t = rbind(data.frame(aa = "default",
                           bb = 1000000,cc = 2.0,dd = 20000, ee = 40,ff = 00 , gg = 00), this_table())
      this_table(t)
    })

    observeEvent(input$delete_btn, {
      t = this_table()
      print(nrow(t))
      if (!is.null(input$shiny_table_rows_selected)) {
        t <- t[-as.numeric(input$shiny_table_rows_selected),]
      }
      this_table(t)
    })

     v <- reactiveValues(data = demodata)
    # #
     proxy = dataTableProxy("mod_table")
    # #
     observeEvent(input$mod_table_cell_edit, {
       print(names(v$data))
       info = input$mod_table_cell_edit
       str(info)
       i = info$row
       j = info$col
       k = info$value
       str(info)
    # #
       isolate(
         if (j %in% match(c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg"), names(v$data))) {
        #   print(match(c("ratio","cost", "updated_price"), names(v$data)))
           v$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, v$data[i, j])
           print(v$data)
    # #
    # #
           if (j %in% match("reach_percentage", names(v$data))) {
             v$data$ff <<- v$data$dd / 10000
           }
         } else {
           stop("You are not supposed to change this column.") # check to stop the user from editing only few columns
         }
       )
       replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
     })
    # 
     observeEvent(input$reset, {
       this_table <- input_data # your default data
     })
    # #

    output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(this_table(), selection = 'single',editable = TRUE, options = list(dom = 't'))

    })


  }
)
```

Comment: Does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main challenge is that your column data looses its type (numeric) while you extract the updated cell data from the table. Ensure that column dd is numeric, before doing your calculation.

```
observeEvent(input$mod_table_cell_edit, {
  info = input$mod_table_cell_edit
  v$data[info$row, info$col] <- info$value
  v$data$ff <- as.numeric(v$data$dd) / 10000
  replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)
})
```

Concerning your new column, you could just add the calculation:

```
observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
  t = rbind(data.frame(aa = "default", bb = 1000000, cc = 2.0, dd = 20000, 
                       ee = 40,ff = 00 , gg = 00), this_table())
  t$ff <- as.numeric(t$dd) / 10000
  this_table(t)
})
```

**Reproducible code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

### Data
input_data <- data.frame(aa = c("Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3"),
                         bb = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                         cc = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         dd = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                         ee = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         ff = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         gg = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### Shiny App
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    mainPanel(

      actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
      actionButton("add_btn", "Add"),
      actionButton("delete_btn", "Delete"),
      tags$hr(),
      DT::dataTableOutput("mod_table")    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    demodata<-input_data

    this_table <- reactiveVal(input_data)

    observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
      t = rbind(data.frame(aa = "default",
                           bb = 1000000,cc = 2.0,dd = 20000, ee = 40,ff = 00 , 
                           gg = 00), this_table())
      this_table(t)
    })

    observeEvent(input$delete_btn, {
      t = this_table()
      print(nrow(t))
      if (!is.null(input$shiny_table_rows_selected)) {
        t <- t[-as.numeric(input$shiny_table_rows_selected),]
      }
      this_table(t)
    })

    v <- reactiveValues(data = demodata)

    proxy = dataTableProxy("mod_table")

    observeEvent(input$mod_table_cell_edit, {
      info = input$mod_table_cell_edit
      v$data[info$row, info$col] <- info$value
      v$data$ff <- as.numeric(v$data$dd) / 10000
      replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)
    })
    # 
    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      this_table <- input_data # your default data
    })
    # #

    output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(this_table(), selection = 'single',editable = TRUE, 
                options = list(dom = 't'))

    })


  }
)
```